# JQuery Mobile + ListView Refresh + Get

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

I'm trying to use listview refresh when getting results and printing in a listview. What's wrong??

HTML:

```
<div id="div1">
<ul id="uf" data-role='listview' data-inset='true' data-filter='true' data-filter-placeholder='Pesquise...' data-theme='a'>
</ul>
</div>
```

AJAX:

```
function menu(){
        $.ajax({
          url: 'http://xxxxxxxx.com/vs.asp?tp=uf&q='+str,
          success: function(data) {
            $('#uf').append( data );
            $('#uf').listview();
          },
          complete: function() {
            $('#uf').listview('refresh');
            } 
        });
        }
```

vs.asp:

```
response.write "<li class='estados'>" & rs("estado_nome") & "</a></li>"
```

Can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: No. When i open the page, the results are printed like a list, with bullets.When i type something on the listview filter, then the results are printed like a listview.

Comment: if you are seeing the list items, remove the ($('#uf').listview();) and amend ($('#uf').listview('refresh');) to ($('#uf').listview().listview('refresh');). see if that helps

Comment: It might be a typo, but in the vs.asp you are missing the opening anchor tag "<a href='#' >"

Comment: Also, when are you refreshing the listview? on button click, page load, etc.?